# Create widget-like buttons from java

Tags: android, xml, widget, styles, parameters

I'd like to dynamically create buttons that look exactly like the buttons I create by declaring a widget "Button" in xml. This code:

```
Button myButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myButton.setText("dinamic");  //Integer.toString(i)
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.supbarL);
ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

creates black weird-looking buttons... Is there a way to get and set the style of a view to be equal to a standard-looking widget or to another view? Also, where can I find the xml definitions of the different themes?

Comment: this should create a standard button only. what do you see black weird-looking buttons.?

Comment: Thanks for answering, here's a screen. "Dinamic" buttons is what I get when I create them from java, normal buttons are those declared directly in xml: [screenshot](http://imgur.com/z2le5Mu) Let me know if you need all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue could be that you have set the base theme in manifest.

Try to change the theme to light/dark

*Android with support library*

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

*Android without support library*

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.Light"
```